# Как вывести данные из таблицы MySQL с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

У меня есть база данных MySQL под названием "test", в этой базе данных есть таблица "click". В это таблице есть три столбца "username", "password" и "click". 
Как вывести данные из таблицы "click" на страницу, если занесённый в переменную текст будет совпадать с одной из записей в столбце "username"?

Код подключения к базе данных

```
<?
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

Comment: к базе подключились, дальше то в чем проблема? не можете запрос написать на выборку?

Comment: Вот это как раз таки я и не могу, поэтому и написал сюда.

Comment: конкретизируйте проблему. вы не знаете синтаксис SQL для написания запроса, либо не знаете как выполнить его с помощью пхп ? Вы пробовали справку прочитать, там же куча примеров кода. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php вот пример выполнения запроса с параметрами (insert) и далее выборка результата.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы из таблицы (https://pp.userapi.com/c848528/v848528473/188f41/wFp9Fj_f_p8.jpg) выводилась значение click у пользователя tiamenty на страницу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставьте этот код после вашего:

```
$query = "SELECT click FROM click WHERE username = 'tiamenty'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$returned = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
mysqli_free_result($result);

echo $returned['click'];
```